# querySelectorAll not working in my script

Tags: javascript

i have problem with querySelectorAll.

This is my code:

```
$(window).load(
    function() {

        // Add animations
        var wwa = document.querySelectorAll(".wwa-box");

        if (window.innerWidth > 992) {
            wwa.classList.add("bounceIn");
        }

        // WOW init
        new WOW().init();

    }
);
```

Console:

```
TypeError: wwa.classList is undefined
```

I want to add class **.bonuceIn** to all tags with class **.wwa-box**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `wwa` is a collection. You can use a simple loop to iterate it and add the class. See this [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/48yfjap0/1/)

```
  for (i = 0; i < wwa.length; i++){
     wwa[i].classList.add("bounceIn");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

because it is a nodeList collection and you treat it as a single item. You need to loop though them all and set the classList.

```
var wwa = document.querySelectorAll(".wwa-box");
for (var i=0; i<wwa.length; i++) {
     wwa[i].classList.add("bounceIn");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is cause `wwa` is `NodeList`, if there is only one element with class `wwa-box` you can use `document.querySelector(".wwa-box");` it returns only first element, or use foreach if you have few `.wwa-box`.

Answer (score -1):

As said by the console:

TypeError: wwa.classList is undefined

Is this property really with wwa? Shouldn't you put a debbuger and navigate and see the properties that it have?

Using the other answer, see the index after and use a for to navigate and add the class.